# How to determine the solution to the schrödinger equation for the particle in a box problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

In [this](https://youtu.be/LBB39u8dNw0) YouTube video about the particle in a box problem:

He determines that $\psi(x)=A\sin(kx)+B\cos(kx)$ is the solution to the time-independent Schrödinger equation, which is:
$$\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+k^2\psi=0$$
but he decides to not explain how this solution was determined. I was hoping somebody would be able to help me understand how to come up with that equation on my own. I know this is probably very simple, but I’m trying to learn quantum mechanics while not being very knowledgeable in math.

Comment: The equation is saying that the second derivative of a function is a constant multiple of the function itself. The only elementary functions that satisfy this property are sine and cosine (which are representations of complex exponentials).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of differential equations are not solved by a fixed method, but rather by guessing and playing around with the equation until you find an insight. So, since there's not a formal 'derivation' for guessing, people often just give you the solution. Yours is an example of a differential question that is often just guessed.

How to guess it? Notice that your differential equation says that two derivatives just give a constant factor in front of the original function. You might remember that the second derivatives of sines and cosines just give back sines and cosines, up to a factor. So, playing around with sines and cosines until you find the most general working solution would solve this equation for you.